# Can iodine hydrocarbons be used as fire extinguishing agent? What are their properties?

Tags: halides

In the German Wikipedia the following claim about fire extinguishing agents is made:

> Iodkohlenwasserstoffe haben zwar eine hervorragende Löschwirkung,
>   erlangten wegen ihres exorbitant hohen Preises (in den 1950ern etwa
>   Faktor 10 gegenüber Bromkohlenwasserstoffen) jedoch niemals Bedeutung.

Translated:

> Though iodine hydrocarbons have excellent fire extinguishing properties
>   they never became important because of their exorbitant prices (during
>   the 1950s they were approximately 10 times more expensive than bromide
>   hydrocarbons).

Now I am curious because I never heard of iodine hydrocarbons. What are their properties and what advantages would they have over the traditional halogen (fluoride, chloride, bromide) components if price is irrelevant?

Comment: Funny, Professor Knochel stated in a lecture that if $\ce{Ar-Cl}$ costs \$1 per gram, $\ce{Ar-Br}$ will cost \$10 per gram and $\ce{Ar-I}$ \$1000 per gram resulting in a factor of $100$.